# Customizing Permissions and Groups models in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I want to modify the Permissions and Group models from `django.contrib.auth`. I have extended them but am unable to understand how to use these extended models in my project. I had researched about it again and again but could not find the solution. Can any one help me?

I had to add two extra fields in Permission model and 4 additional fields in Group model. I had extended both models but when I replace the permissions attribute of Group class it gives [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfQ11.png) that local fields cannot replace existing.
Further, I cannot use add/contribute to original class methods as it is dangerous to replace original files and is not a good programming practice too.
Is there any way to change *permissions* in **Group** model.
Secondly, how can I use these new models in **User** model?

Answer (score 0):

the error is quite clear. You cannot have a property on the class that is already implemented by the base class.

Do you need to inherit from the permissions class?
Could you edit it instead?

Comment: Yes, I cannot edit the permission class because it is part of base Django framework. I need to inherit it to replace add new fields, but I am unable to use new CustomPermission class with Group and User models (classes)